# Adding toList() to the map() changes the list

Tags: dart

Here is my code:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final cars = [
    new CarModel("BMW", "1995", 130),
    new CarModel("Audi", "2000", 150),
  ];

  final mapped = cars.map((e) {
    if (e.name == "BMW") {
      e.name = "Ford";
    }
    return e;
  }).toList(); //Magic happens here

  cars.forEach((element) {
    print(element.name);
  });
  mapped.forEach((element) {
    print(element.name);
  });
}

class CarModel {
  CarModel(this._name, this._year, this._money, {isNew = false})
      : _isNew = isNew;

  final bool _isNew;
  final int _money;
  String _name;
  final String _year;

  String get name => _name;

  String get year => _year;

  int get money => _money;

  bool get isNew => _isNew;

  set name(String newName) {
    _name = newName;
  }
}
```

When I add toList() to the map() method, it changes my list(cars). I tried the same scenario in a different code but it just happens on that code only. So why does the toList() method changes my list?

For more explanation:

The output when you add toList():

> print(cars) -> Ford Audi
>
> print(mapped) -> Ford Audi

The output when you dont add toList():

> print(cars) -> BMW Audi
>
> print(mapped) -> Ford Audi

Comment: Your `.map` callback mutates the `List` elements, but [`Iterable.map` is *lazy*](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) and won't invoke the callbacks until the elements are accessed. `.toList()` necessarily accesses all elements, thus triggering the callback for each element.

Comment: @jamesdlin but I tried the same thing with list<int> and it doesn't mutate the list.

Comment: Your `map` callback doesn't mutate the `List` itself; it mutates the *elements*.  If you tried `cars.map((e) => e = CarModel('', '', 0)).toList();`, you also would not see any change to `cars` because the callback only reassigns a local variable (`e`); it does not mutate an existing `CarModel` object.  Similarly, for a `List<int>`, it is not possible to mutate any of the elements since `int`s are immutable.

Comment: BTW, using `Iterable.map` with a callback that mutates elements is very bad style.  It's meant for a functional programming style where the callback does not have side effects.  This is why the behavior you observe isn't very intuitive.

Comment: @jamesdlin It took a while but I finally got it. Thank you so much. I will keep that in my mind.